# SSRS 2008 - computing a sum while ignoring some columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I swear this shouldn't be that hard, but it's been a real struggle.

I have a query that returns a site name, an event date, and the count of events.  I use it in a very nice chart to show events by day.

I now want a Tablix to show the sum of those count of events by site.  That is, ignore the date and just sum the counts.

I know I can write another query to accomplish this, but I'd rather minimize the number of queries in this report.  How can I use the existing query to create the Tablix that I want?

Answer (score 0):

in the tablix, create your group/groups that you want to sum by, then add the sum of the field you're summing.  If you exlude the date in the groups then it'll just sum by whatever you group by.